# About the requirement of iids to form a martingale

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, markov-process, iid, martingale

Most problems about martingales start with an assertion similar to the following one:

*Suppose that $X_n$ are iid such that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$. Then $S_n = \sum_i^n X_i$ is a martingale.*

Why do we require $X_n$ to be iid? Can the previous statement be extended or generalized (maybe under certain assumptions) to the case of $X_n$ being identical but dependent variables or to non-identical but independent variables?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the writer is interested in iid variables, and so not (at the moment) interested in generalizations ... but clearly some can be done. If you keep the independence, but drop identical, and of course keep
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
    \E X_n =0  $$
then you can easily check that $S_n$ still is a martingale.

Dropping the independence assumption can of course be done in infinitely many ways, so you would need to tell us in which direction you are interested ... but, for instance, if
$$ \E [ X_{n+1} \mid X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n ] =0 $$
(but maybe the variance, say, changes ...)  then you can still check the definitions and find that $S_n$ still is a martingale sequence.

The talk [https://math.bme.hu/~simonk/mm/File_A_8.pdf](https://math.bme.hu/%7Esimonk/mm/File_A_8.pdf)  gives examples of martingales build from Markov processes.